# Slim PHP Framework causing 'Fail to open page'

Tags: php, api, safari, slim

I have set up a REST API using the Slim PHP framework, which works perfectly when using requests i.e http://mysite.com/class/id.

But when I navigate to http://mysite.com/, I get the following error in Safari:

> Safari can’t open the page “http://mysite.com/”.
>
> The error is: “cannot decode raw data” (NSURLErrorDomain:-1015)
>
> Please choose Safari > Report Bugs to Apple, note the error number,
>   and describe what you did before you saw this message.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
include_once('config.php');
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->post('/user/create', 'create_user');
$app->get('/user/:id', 'info_user');
$app->post('/user/:id', 'update_user');
$app->delete('/user/:id', 'delete_user');
$app->post('/user/validate', 'validate_user');
$app->get('/user/:id/venues', 'venues_user');
$app->get('/user/:id/queues', 'queues_user');

$app->post('/venue', 'create_venue');
$app->post('/venue/:id', 'update_venue');
$app->delete('/venue/:id', 'delete_venue');
$app->get('/venue/:id', 'info_venue');
$app->get('/venue/:id/queues', 'queues_venue');

$app->post('/queue', 'create_queue');
$app->post('/queue/:id', 'update_queue');
$app->delete('/queue/:id', 'delete_queue');
$app->get('/queue/:id', 'info_queue');

$app->run();
```

Comment: +1 for using Slim PHP. I've never used it but it looks like a great _slim_ framework!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using PHPFog and Slim, you have to set the HTTP Version to 1.0 rather than 1.1.

You can do this by adding a parameter to the variable:

```
$app = new Slim(array('http.version' => '1.0'));
```

This was solved thanks to the help of the Slim framework creator!

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need an entry such as:

`$app->get('/', 'index_page');`

Comment: What would you suggest I put in the `index_page` function?

Comment: I guess whatever you want to actually show up when someone browses to http://mysite.com/ ... ?

Comment: It didn't make any difference, the site still displays the same error.